# ActionBar tabs have space before them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have an app that has transparent actionBar and is using AppCompat support library. My problem is that I want to align my ActionBarTabs to the very left but there is some space left and I want to get rid of it. Also, how to properly align the icons with the rest ? Is that in the size of icons ?

Here is the screenshot of my app:

[image: Actionbar]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 24x24 icon you will be fine. Try go to [here](http://materialdesignicons.com) download any icons you want and use the icons with `24dp.png` in filename and see how it looks.

Comment: Hey, those icons look good but this haven't solved that alignement issue